# Numpy Reshape in PythonNet

Tags: python, c#, numpy, python.net

I'm using pythonnet to use numpy in c#. I want to reshape an array but it seems to not work and I cant seem to understand why. at first i thought there was a problem with the complex array but then i tried it with int and it was the same

here is the code

```cs
using System.Numerics;
using Python.Runtime;

static void Initialize()
{
    string pythonDll = @"C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.dll";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonDll);
    PythonEngine.Initialize();    
}


Initialize();
Complex[] complexes = [
new Complex(1.0, 2.0),
new Complex(3.0, 4.0),
new Complex(5.0, 6.0),
new Complex(5.0, 6.0)

];
List<Complex> comlist = new List<Complex>(complexes);

using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
    dynamic rawData = np.array(comlist);
    np.reshape(a: rawData.T, newshape:(2, 2), order:'F');
}
```

and the error message:

```
Unhandled exception. Python.Runtime.PythonException: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer
  File "C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 44, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 67, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 299, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in reshape
   at Python.Runtime.PythonException.ThrowLastAsClrException()
   at Python.Runtime.PyObject.Invoke(PyTuple args, PyDict kw)
   at Python.Runtime.PyObject.InvokeMethod(String name, PyTuple args, PyDict kw)
   at Python.Runtime.PyObject.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Object, Object, ValueTuple`2, Char)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Mohsen\RiderProjects\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 29
```

Answer (score 0):

The reshape size must be a PyTuple object for it to work other wise it doesnt so thats that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think `numpy` expects sequences of numbers or sequences of sequences for multidimensional arrays, and it has its own data type for complex numbers. The way you're trying to reshape the array using `np.reshape(a: rawData.T, newshape:(2, 2), order:'F')` is correct in terms of function parameters, but `.T` is a shorthand for the transpose operation. If your intention was just to reshape the array, you don't necessarily need to transpose it first.

We should convert the `Complex` objects to a numpy-understandable format. Since `numpy` has its own complex number type, we need to convert your `System.Numerics.Complex` array to a format `numpy` can work with. A straightforward way is to convert each `Complex` object to a tuple `(real, imaginary)` and then let `numpy` handle these tuples.
Then we will use the reshaped array directly or assign it to a variable. `numpy.reshape` doesn't modify the array in place; instead, it returns a new array.

```cs
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Python.Runtime;

static void Initialize()
{
    string pythonDll = @"C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.dll";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonDll);
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Initialize();

    Complex[] complexes = new Complex[]
    {
        new Complex(1.0, 2.0),
        new Complex(3.0, 4.0),
        new Complex(5.0, 6.0),
        new Complex(7.0, 8.0)
    };

    List<object> comlist = new List<object>();
    foreach (var complex in complexes)
    {
        comlist.Add(new PyTuple(new PyObject[] { new PyFloat(complex.Real), new PyFloat(complex.Imaginary) }));
    }

    using (Py.GIL()) // Python Global Interpreter Lock is acquired
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        dynamic rawData = np.array(comlist, dtype: np.complex);
        dynamic reshapedData = np.reshape(rawData, newshape: (2, 2), order: 'F');
        Console.WriteLine(reshapedData);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.